# How to convert time string into date and time format?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, format

I having a hard time trying to format a string time into MM:DD::YY and only time. From an IP i getting the time in the following format

```
2021-09-10T00:37:42Z
```

and I'm want to display the date and time in:

```
09/08/2021
```

Time

```
09:50PM
```

Comment: Look into DateTimeFormatter
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Into what time zone does 00:37:42 on the 10th become become 21:50 on the 8th?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parse the given string into `OffsetDateTime` and then get `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` parts out of it.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-09-10T00:37:42Z";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        LocalTime time = odt.toLocalTime();
        LocalDate date = odt.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(date);

        // #########Custom formats #########

        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedDateString = date.format(dtfDate);
        System.out.println(formattedDateString);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedTimeString = time.format(dtfTime);
        System.out.println(formattedTimeString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
00:37:42
2021-09-10
09/10/2021
12:37 AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/BGjqFQ)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Update based on an important comment by [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v)**:

> The OP — or their user — may want the date and time in their own time
> zone.

In order to get the date and time parts in a specific timezone e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`, you should parse the given date-time string into `ZonedDateTime` and convert the same to the `ZonedDateTime` of the specific timezone using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-). Rest of the things will remain same as the original answer.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-09-10T00:37:42Z";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);

        ZonedDateTime zdtLosAngeles = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

        LocalTime time = zdtLosAngeles.toLocalTime();
        LocalDate date = zdtLosAngeles.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(date);

        // #########Custom formats #########

        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedDateString = date.format(dtfDate);
        System.out.println(formattedDateString);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedTimeString = time.format(dtfTime);
        System.out.println(formattedTimeString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
17:37:42
2021-09-09
09/09/2021
05:37 PM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CiGwmK)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>